# How do I fire a warning shot?

Tags: la-noire

There's an achievement in LA Noire for stopping a fleeing suspect with a warning shot.

How do I do the warning shot? I tried firing "around" the suspect while he's running, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take aim at the suspect (LT on the Xbox), a circle will fill up while you maintain your aim on the suspect. When the circle fills completely, then it will make the warning shot. You also have to be a detective for the achievement, and can only accomplish this on chases where you have the gun in your hand.

You can find a couple of guides [here](http://www.trueachievements.com/a151041/not-so-hasty-achievement.htm?showguides=1).

Answer (score -1):

To fire a warning shot in L.A. Noire, you have to be in a chase sequence, and you must already have your gun drawn. (If your gun isn't drawn, you can't fire a warning shot.)

When the suspect is fleeing, hold your left trigger button (LT on Xbox) and a circle will show up on the screen while you are aimed at the suspect. This circle will slowly fill up (you must keep aiming at the suspect!), and when it is completely full, you will go into a very brief cut-scene that will show your character firing the shot and your suspect freezing in his tracks.

For more info and a video, click here:
http://www.sleeandtopher.com/l-a-noire-how-to-fire-a-warning-shot/

Comment: you kinda just copied doozer blakes answer..

Comment: Unless you don't have anything _new_ to add to this question, please don't post rehashed answers just to promote your own site, that sort of behavior is **not** tolerated here.